# MariaDB function syntax error when creating a function

Tags: mariadb

I've made this function but no matter what I add (delimiters) it's still throwing the same error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNumberOfBuyers(IN userId INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
   DECLARE numberOfBuyers INT DEFAULT 0;
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numberOfBuyers FROM buyers WHERE id = userId;
   RETURN numberOfBuyers;
END;
```

The error is:

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
> to use near 'IN userId INT) RETURNS INT BEGIN DECLARE numberOfBuyers
> INT DEFAULT 0; ...' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possibility to mark parameter as input parameter in mariadb. So remove the `IN` in the declaration:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNumberOfBuyers(userId INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
   DECLARE numberOfBuyers INT DEFAULT 0;
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numberOfBuyers FROM buyers WHERE id = userId;
   RETURN numberOfBuyers;
END;
```

The general syntax declaration looks like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION function_name [ (parameter datatype [, parameter datatype]) ]
RETURNS return_datatype

BEGIN

   declaration_section

   executable_section

END;
```

Comment: Since 10.8.0 MariaDB supports IN, OUT and IN OUT. However, I ran into the same problem because I was executing my code on a new and on an old MariaDB installation and it worked only on the new MariaDB installation.